# How do I append columns in a specific row using pandas python in a pd.Excel() dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

This is what I have to locate and read the specific row:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pandas as pd
import datetime


file = input("name of file: ")
file1 = str(file) +'.xlsx'


xl = pd.ExcelFile(file1)

print (xl.sheet_names)

time = datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now())
t = time.strftime("%H:%M")

date = datetime.date.today()
d = date.strftime("%m-%d-%y")


def print_excel():
    inp = input("name: ")
    if inp in str(xl.sheet_names):
        print ("true")
        matching = [s for s in xl.sheet_names if inp in s]
        m = str(matching).strip("'[]")
        df = pd.ExcelFile.parse(xl, sheet_name=m, inplace=True,usecols="A,G:L")
        with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', 300, 'display.max_columns', 0, 'display.expand_frame_repr', False):
            k = df.keys()[0]

            print(df[(df[str(k)] == date)])

    else:
        print("failed")
        return print_excel()


print_excel()
```

The Code above returns the row for the current date, I need to get that specific row and edit the columns for it.

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected output? Do you need `df.loc[(df[str(k)] == date), 'column_name'] = 100` ?

Comment: yes, apparently, thank you.